# grep find character without character afterwards

Tags: regex, grep

Hi a grep regex question I think

I have many cases of two similar terms in a file eg:

```
 'stop_codon,5UTR' & 'stop_codon'
```

The longer term is always the first term, a comma, then an additional term.
I want to use grep to find cases of one but not the other. So how can I tell grep to find only those terms that are not immediately followed by a ','.

Simple I am sure but I have little experience with regular expressions and I could'nt find a way to find an occurrence of one term unless it includes another term.

Thanks in advance,
Rubal

Comment: That depends. What follows the longer term if it is not followed by the comma and the second one? The end of the line would be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work

```
'stop_condon[^,]'
```

where you use a negated character class

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: That only words if there is a non-comma following.  It doesn’t work if there is nothing at all following.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, I am trying to find the cases with nothing following, and exclude the cases where a comma follows.

Comment: @user964689: If you're parsing CSV files, then you might be better off with a CSV processing module in the language of your choice. There are many quirks and caveats to CSV files that make home-grown solutions hard to get right

Comment: That won't work if really nothing follows the term it works only if any character but a comma follows the term (e.g. a collon, dash, digit or word character). That's why I was asking what could possibly follow your search term in your file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-P` option to match with a `perl` regex pattern:

```
$ grep -P 'stop_codon(?!,)' file.txt
```

Comment: @user964689 It works when lines only contain **`stop_codon`**.